# ng-include prohibits routes to be run

Tags: angularjs

I have a very strange behavior in an AngularJS app: I am registering routes using the $routeProvider. This works perfectly unless I embed an `ng-include` element *BEFORE* the `ng-view`.

Currently I have two options to fix it:

- Move the `ng-include` to a place after the `ng-view` element.
- Wrap the `ng-include` inside a `<div>` element.

Any idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: You are not alone, my friend! I had this same issue and I've been trying to fix it for like an hour now!!! It seems to ONLY be when the div are siblings (or at least, that is one case that triggers this issue). It's like it just renders anything routing related inert to have `<div ng-include="'...'"></div><div ng-view></div>`. WTF...

Comment: I've done this exact thing in some apps I've written and it worked fine.  Perhaps the angular version you're using has a bug.  Hard to say without being able to reproduce myself.

Comment: What issue are you facing? Is the template referenced in the include not loading or the routing not working?

Answer (score 1):

Try it as

```
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-include src="template">

    angular.module('App')
        .controller('MainCtrl',['$route','$scope', function($route,$scope){
                $scope.template= 'main.html';
        }]);

In main.html, place the ng-view tag.
```

In this case, you need to handle ng-include with the controller and inject $route as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

i too had some issues with the $route.
one idea that solved my problems was to just use ng-switch for the ng-include instead of ng-view
[Conditional ng-include in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974086/conditional-ng-include-in-angularjs)