# Conditional ng-include in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

How can I do the ng-include conditionally in angularJS?

For example I only want to include something if, the variable `x` is set to `true`.

```
<div ng-include="/partial.html"></div>
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If you are using Angular v1.1.5 or later, you can also use [ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngIf):

```
<div ng-if="x" ng-include="'/partial.html'"></div>
```

---

If you have any older version:

Use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch):

```
<div ng-switch on="x">
   <div ng-switch-when="true" ng-include="'/partial.html'"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/pMp9M/)

Comment: Yes, it is currently broken in 1.2: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3627

Comment: The issue was fixed in v1.2.2-23ba287 http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3627#issuecomment-23539882 ; in current versions (1.2.*) you cannot use ng-switch and ng-include on the same element, so you need something like: <div ng-switch-when="true"><div ng-include="'something'"></div><//div>

Answer (score 69):

You could also do

```
<div ng-include="getInclude()"></div>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.getInclude = function(){
    if(x){
        return "partial.html";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Just really nice.  The `ng-switch` marked answer didn't work for me.

Comment: Is a Controller appropriate for set view files? i think, No. @Mark Rajcok answer is true.

Answer (score 17):

A little bit more readable version of one of the answers. Plus setting `ng-include` to `null` removes the element - just like `ng-if`.

```
<div ng-include="x ? 'true-partial.html' : null"></div>
```

Answer (score 12):

If the condition is simple enough, you could also put the conditional logic directly in the ng-include expression:

```
<div ng-include="x && 'true-partial.html' || 'false-partial.html'"></div>
```

Note the expression `x` is not in single quotes and therefore evaluated. See http://plnkr.co/edit/4fvNDa6Gm3dbVLgsAZrA for more details.

Comment: I would say the accepted solution is actually more readable since the check condition and actual include are nicely separated.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue and may be this finding can help someone. I have to display different partials on click of link but ng-if and ng-switch both were not working in this scenario(Below code was not working).

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="viewType('LIST')">List All</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="viewType('EDIT')">Edit</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="viewType('VIEW')">View</button>

<section class="col-md-8 left-col">
    <span ng-if = "LIST">
        <div data-ng-include="'./app/view/articles/listarticle.html'">
    </span>
    <span ng-if = "EDIT">
        <div data-ng-include="'./app/view/articles/editorarticle.html'">
    </span>

</section>
```

So what I did is, instead of using ng-if, On click of link just update the value of partialArticleUrl (which is a model in controller) and declare below code on html.

```
        <section class="col-md-8 left-col">
            <div data-ng-include="partialArticleUrl">
        </section>
```