# In AngularJS 1.2, how do I specify the controller for an ng-include?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

We are attempting to upgrade from AngularJS 1.0.7 to 1.2.1.  In 1.0.7, we were able to set the controller for an ng-include alongside in the same element, like so

```
<div data-ng-include="'include1.html'" data-ng-controller="MyCtrl1"
```

`MyCtrl1` would become available to the code inside `include1.html`.

This breaks when moving to AngularJS 1.2.1 which I have illustrated in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cWiOIK6ItuJ6j3Y7HxHz?p=preview).  If you change the referenced version to 1.0.7 it [works](http://plnkr.co/edit/TsuFnuAWGvqd7pg9ozMG?p=preview) again.

I am interested in understanding what has changed/why this is.  I tried searching but couldn't find anything or I am not using the right terms.

Additionally, what would be the correct way to specify a controller for my `ng-include`s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not move the `ng-controller` from the element having `ng-include` to inside the template:

index.html:

```
<div data-ng-include="'include1.html'"></div>    
<div data-ng-include="'include2.html'"></div>
```

include1.html

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
    <h1>{{Username}}</h1>
</div>
```

include2.html

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
    <h1>{{Username}}</h1>
</div>
```

It seems `ngController` and `ngInclude` cannot be used in conjunction with each other since Angular version 1.2:

[Issue 1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4431), [Issue 2](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4521), [Issue 3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3584#issuecomment-25857079) and [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408321/ng-include-onload-not-working-anymore-in-angularjs-1-2-0-rc).

Comment: I am interested in understanding why this is happening and what has changed, any ideas?

Comment: I think this has got to do with the newer version not allowing multiple directives on the same element.

Comment: I have attached few links.

Comment: Fantastic, I did see the post by Igor Minar but skimmed it by. Thanks for pointing at the right place!

Comment: I've noticed ng-include creates child scope.. does this approach mean you get a grand-child scope created?

Comment: Nesting the ng-include element inside the ng-controller element doesn't seem to work when using $compile....