# How to redirect to a different template based on the scope in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-template

I would like to have a different template based on my scope.

Currently, I have only one template named : `view-project.html` accessible by this url : `#/project/:id`.

Now, I need two templates : `view-project-1.html` and `view-project-2.html`.
and I need them to keep the same url : `#/project/:id`

So for example, if my $scope.template = 1, I would like to use `view-project-1.html` with this url `#/project/300`. And if `$scope.template = 2` I would like to use `view-project-2.html` with this url #/project/300

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: The best answer to my question is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15976268/387912

Answer (score 2):

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/project/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            controller: 'projectcontroller'
        })
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
app.controller('projectcontroller', function($scope) {
    $scope.template = 2;
});
```

template.html:

```
<div ng-include="template==2?'view-project-2.html':'view-project-1.html'"></div>
```

**[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/MSBlFz7vbaStO3ncUuYq?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

This, according to me, can be done in the following way :

1. Use ng-include to import both of your templates in the same file.
2. You can use ng-switch or ng-if to render one of the two templates based on the values in the route parameters.