# AngularJS: ng-if plus ng-include throws TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm writing an app using [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) (version v1.0.0-beta.11), but I believe this question is rather related with the underlying AngularJS (version v1.2.17).

I have a problem when using `ng-if` and `ng-include` together in the same element. When the condition of the `ng-if` changes in the model, I get the following error (tested both in Chrome and Android):

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10843:14
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8187:18)
    at forEach.after (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10842:5)
    at Object.JQLite.(anonymous function) [as after] (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10913:17)
    at Object.enter (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12015:17)
    at Object.enter (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30107:21)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27441:26
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13779:29)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13894:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14492:18)
```

I've isolated the issue in a simple project based on the Ionic starter project (`ionic start [PATH] tabs`). Here's the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/CczR5NgFLqR143jQJ08C?p=preview

I dug into the error and found that the function that is throwing the error is `after: function(element, newElement) {...`.
Printing out the arguments passed the function, `element` is an `[object Comment]` with contents `<!-- ngInclude: -->` and `newElement` is an `[[object HTMLDivElement]]`.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15974160/2050333) that both directives `ng-if` and `ng-include` can be combined since Angular 1.2.2.

Has anyone experienced this issue?. Is there any known fix (other than moving the `ng-if` to a parent element)?.

Thanks in advance,

  Rafa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `ng-if` and `ng-include` are queued up to execute, and `ng-if` has a higher priority so it runs first. If the expression is false, then `ng-if` removes the element, but doesn't cancel the `ng-include` from running. Since the element is removed, `ng-include` is unable to inject the loaded content into the element and you get this error.

You could consider having an expression in `ng-include` and remove the `ng-if`. If the expression returns an empty string, `ng-include` will not try to load anything.

Forked your plunkr and have the content load after 2 seconds: http://plnkr.co/edit/oTnJ0bTlMBD7yrUmPloq?p=preview

**Markup**

```
<ng-include src="source"></ng-include>
```

**Controller**

```
// In the controller, check
$timeout(function () {
  $scope.source = 'templates/Nocontent.html';
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Just for the record, if the condition is a different variable in the model, `"<div ng-include src="!content ? 'templates/mytemplate.html' : null"></div>` works fine.

Comment: Also be aware that even if the `div` element is not appended when the `ng-include` condition is false, any associated controller (using `ng-controller`) will be invoked.

Comment: Actually the controllers are called but with an empty `$scope`

Comment: If using `ng-controller` together with a conditional `ng-include`, note that the controller will be run only once: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26006589/2050333