# Conditional ng-include together with ng-controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a conditional `ng-include` directive with a `ng-controller` associated, but it seems the controller isn't run when the condition is true.
The target is to include the template only when the condition is met and avoid the [`TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null` issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667705/angularjs-ng-if-plus-ng-include-throws-typeerror-cannot-call-method-insertbef/25674022).

For example:

```
<div ng-include src="myContent.imgList ? 'ui/image-list.html' : null" ng-controller="ImgListSubCtrl">
</div>
```

When `myContent.imgList` is filled with data, I expect the `image-list.html` template to be appended to the DOM and `ImgListSubCtrl` to be run, but it isn't.

Is this the expected behavior?. I'm using Ionic Framework with Angular 1.2.17.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found an explanation, though further comments are welcome.

The following Codepen shows the mentioned behavior and the solution (in Ionic Framework 1.0.0-beta12): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FnojD?editors=101
The first include doesn't display any count, though the second one displays it correctly.

It seems that when using `ng-include` along with `ng-controller`, the controller is only run once, even when the `ng-include src` expression evaluates to `null`.
To run it when the template is actually included (when `ng-include src` isn't `null`), a solution is to avoid the conditional `ng-include` and wrap it in a `ng-if` block, so the whole element is re-created dynamically, as shown in the Codepen above.
In the example from the question:

```
<div ng-if="myContent.imgList">
    <div ng-include src="'ui/image-list.html'" ng-controller="ImgListSubCtrl">
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.