# Resolving issues while upgrading to angularjs 1.3 from 1.0.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, version, upgrade

My application is being upgraded to use angularjs 1.3 from 1.0.5. Because of this several components are broken in the application like "ngRoute" as a separate module, but this is not a big issue.
I have been using multiple directives on the same elements and now this model does not work anymore. If they were my own directives I could have modified the directives but those are `ngDirectives` which I don't know how to fix.
Here is an example which breaks:

```
<div ng-switch-when="view" ng-include=" 'views/view1.html' "></div>
```

and inside 'view1.html' I have something like this:

```
<div ng-grid="gridData"
             ng-switch-when="grid"></div>
```

I tried following:

```
<div ng-switch-when="view1">
        <ng-include src=" 'views/view1.html' "></ng-include>
    </div>
```

I get similar errors like **"multidir"**. I don't know what steps I should I follow to make my application working. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: did you looked at my answer?

Comment: @pankajparkar: Thank you for the quick answer, but I was looking answer with a broader scope.

Comment: @me-digvijay but your question clearly says that your issue with `ng-switch-when` with `ng-include`

Comment: @pankajparkar: Yes, but it is just an example of several other issues that might come during migration

Comment: @me-digvijay Cool..But its look like you need do find it again what you need..just reference doesn't mean you got solution to all of your problem..All up to you..Nice to help you, Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the above solution works, that is only for one case though.
I think you will find most of your answers over here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng-if` instead of `ng-switch-when` to resolve the issue, both work as same.

```
<div ng-if="view" ng-include="'/partial.html'"></div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8wrnbLkd/1/)

For more info Refer this [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15974160/2435473)